# Does javascript use some sort of implicit "noop" call?

Tags: javascript, computer-science

This is probably JS 101 but...

Can someone with a better understanding of JS engines explain to me why string literals, integers and so forth are 'ignored' by JS or treated as otherwise valid code?

JS Hint does give 'unexpected expression' reports however the code remains valid and runs.

I've created the following pen to, hopefully, explain what I mean here.

http://codepen.io/billythekid/pen/zyGbi/

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0];

// let's show what I'm trying to say here by way of an expanded example.
function foo()
{
  var bar = "something";
}
foo(); // does nothing useful, but returns nothing either - valid and understandable;

function baz()
{
  return "nothing"; // a string
}

function zoo()
{
  return 250; // an integer
}

var a = baz(); // the variable holds the return value. The function is evaluated and the return value is assigned to the variable.
span.innerHTML += a+"<br>";

baz(); // produces no error despite the function returning a value. Why doesn't the JS engine see this as the evaluated string "something" and try to run the string as a JS command?
span.innerHTML += "this code has run, so the JS didn't break above. Why wasn't the returned string parsed and invalid?<br>";

"something"; // the string literal
span.innerHTML += "this code has run, so the JS didn't break above. So why not? How is a string literal valid JS? Why no errors?<br>";

var b = zoo();
span.innerHTML += b+"<br>";

zoo();// produces no error despite the function returning a value. Why doesn't the JS engine see this as the evaluated integer 250 and try to run the string as a JS command?
span.innerHTML += "this code has run, so the JS didn't break above. So why not? How is an evaluated integer valid JS? Why no errors?<br>";

250; // the integer literal
span.innerHTML += "this code has run, so the JS didn't break above. So why not? How is an integer literal valid JS? Why no errors?<br>";

eval(250); // the integer literal
span.innerHTML += "this code has run, so the JS didn't break above. So why not? How is an evaluated integer literal valid JS? Why no errors?<br>";

eval("something"); // the string literal
span.innerHTML += "this code broke, it can't run a string that's not been defined as a function or whatever.<br>";

// and, had the previous code not broken...
non_func(); // doesn't exist!
span.innerHTML += "this code doesn't run! So it'll error out with a call to a function/variable that doesn't exist but not eval'd code that isn't JS, such as a string, or even the literals of these objects!<br>";

// It appears that anythign not explicitly wrapped in an eval function is ignored by JS rather than throwing any errors. Why is this?
```

Simply running a string literal such as "foo"; as a line in the console seems to return itself.

Is the JS internally wrapping simple cases like these in some sort of 'noop' method or internally garbage-collecting such things or does it simply see the code as "run" once it's gone past it and has nothing more to do (such as assign values to a variable, or some other thing?

I got to thinking about this when using a setInterval() call, if I assign it's return value (well, it's ID identifier) to a var for using in a clearInterval later it's valid but it's also valid when we ignore the returned ID. The ID isn't "parsed" as JS.

Using strict mode seems to have no effect on this behaviour either.

Hopefully I've not made this more confusing than it needs to be. :oD

Comment: The syntax of the language says that any expression serves as a statement, so that's that. (And yes, you have made this more confusing than it needs to be.)

Comment: _"Hopefully I've not made this more confusing than it needs to be"_ I think you're *waaaay* overthinking this.

Comment: JavaScript is one of the few languages that automatically checks and converts variables as it goes.  That's why it's not necessary to declare a type.  Just set it.  It's also why almost anything can be freely used with no conversion.  Is it dangerous to the lazy programmer?  Probably.  But it does help simplify things.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I suspected this might be something to do with loose typing.

Comment: This has nothing to do with loose typing. Lots of languages like C and Java let you ignore the returned values from subroutines

Comment: I guess that's a good term for it.  The point is, JS is supposed to be easy to use, and easy to learn.  So there are a boatload of shortcuts built in to that effect.  There really is no point in determining how it works.  Just be comforted that it does.

Comment: I presume it "acts" like /dev/null with the return if there's nothing to pass it to?

Comment: It's probably not exactly a noop because, as you know, `use strict` is done in the same way so it probably at least has to check if it's a `use strict` statement. I imagine it can be ignored after that.

Comment: The `eval` calls fail because you're not properly escaping them. Use `eval("125")` and `eval("\"something\";")`, it will work. While `125` is a number literal, `something` is a reference error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One big culprit behind your confusion is the C programming language. In it, many things that you think are statements, such as assignments, are actually expressions.

```
//This is valid C and Javascript code
x = (y += 1);

//We all have been bitten by this one once haven't we?
while(x = y){
}
```

and in order to let these statements be used in lines of their own, there is a rule in the language grammar that lets an expression followed by a semicolon to count as a statement

```
stmt :=
   <if_then_else> |
   <while loop> |
   ... |
   <expression> ';'
```

The rule for evaluating these single-expression statements is that the expression is evaluated for side-effects and its value gets ignored.

Javascript (and lots of other languages) adopted lots of things from the C syntax, including this particular treatment of expressions.  Using a string as a statement does nothing with its value (unless the string is "use strict" - then its a useful hack that does something in new browsers but nothing in the old ones). Using a function call as a statement runs it for side effects and ignores its return value.  Some more stingy languages, such as Haskell or Go will complain if you ignore return values but C and Javascript will just throw them away.

```
-- In Haskell you get a compiler warning for ignoring return values
do
   functionThatReturnsNothing()
   a <- functionThatReturnsAValue()
   _ <- functionThatReturnsAValue() -- unless you ignore it explicitly
```

> It appears that anythign not explicitly wrapped in an eval function is ignored by JS rather than throwing any errors.

Thank god its that way! It would be crazy error prone if things got implicitly eval-ed like that and strings should never be run as code unless you are explicit about it!

Comment: That's a good explanation. I've been accepting that it "just is" for so long I don't notice any more that a 'noop' is sort of happening. I was looking at some old mIRC script code earlier and remembered how that explicitly needs to be told to noop return values or it'll error.  Hence my train of thought here.

Thanks!